# Creating an interactive choropleth map using R

Tags: r, shiny

Does anyone have some sample code I can look at that creates an interactive map in R/Shiny? I would like to be able to have the map zoom in to a specific US State based on the user selection in a drop down

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far I have been able to create a static chorpleth map using county_choropleth function. But my success has ended there despite many days of trying. New to R

Comment: Sounds like you are off to a good start. I would suggest editing this question into a [mcve] so that other people can better assist you.